# css for table with 2 columns, the second column is scrollable

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I would like to make a table on HTML with 2 columns:

[image]

I have made a proof of concept (POC), but the problem is the other rows of that column is not following the longest row.

[image]

I want the pink cells of the 2nd column width to follow the green cell here.

```css
.c1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.c2 {
  width: 200px;
  
  background-color:cyan;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.c2 > div {
width:100%;
}

.outer {
  display: flex
}

div {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.longest {
  display:flex;
  max-height: 20px;
}

.measure {
  width: 403px;
}

body {
  font-size: 20px;
  
}

.box {
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  
  <div class="c1">
    left
    <div>products</div>
    <div> title 1</div>
    <div>title 2</div>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="c2">
    <div class="longest">
      <div class="box">h</div>
      <div class="box">h</div>
      <div class="box">h</div>
            <div class="box">h</div>
            <div class="box">j</div>
    </div>
    <div>empty</div>
    <div>empty</div>
    <div> filter</div>
  </div>
  
  
 
</div>

<div class="measure">sasd</div>
```

I welcome any feedback or change to grid method instead of flexbox. thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Or could you edit my codepen in a way that the green one is indeed longeR? https://codepen.io/plant996/pen/KKEQrwr

Comment: Either you have tabular data in which case you sue a real table or you don't and use `CSS-Grid`!

Answer (score 0):

You can try my approach. For sure there are many ways to do it, but this is the fast one that I came up with:

```css
.c1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.c3
{
  width: 200px;  
  overflow: scroll;  
  background-color:cyan;
}

.c2 {  
  display: inline-table;
}

.c2 > div {
display:flex;
max-height: 23px;//From here set the cell height
}

.outer {
  display: flex
}

div {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.longest {
  display:flex;
  max-height: 20px;
}

.measure {
  width: 403px;
}

body {
  font-size: 20px;
  
}

.box {
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  
  <div class="c1">
    left
    <div>products</div>
    <div> title 1</div>
    <div>title 2</div>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="c3">
    <div class="c2">
        <div class="longest">
          <div class="box">h</div>
          <div class="box">h</div>
          <div class="box">h</div>
                <div class="box">h</div>
                <div class="box">j</div>
        </div>
        <div>empty</div>
        <div>empty</div>
        <div> filter</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  
 
</div>

<div class="measure">sasd</div>
```

Comment: Please add little bit detail or explanation that what you did to solve the problem so it will save much time to read whole code. Thank you